# session laravel de array

Tags: laravel, session, array-bidimensional

gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Quisiera crear una variable de session en laravel, para guardar una relacion, id-cant, id-cant,
es como un array de array.

he encontrado que para crear una variable en session de laravel.

```
session(['idCarrito' => '123456']);
```

Para obtener su valor:

```
$valor_almacenado = session('idCarrito');
```

pero esto no me sirve, por que necesitaria agregar un array.
donde con un foreach, yo recorra el arreglo y esto me diga algo como por ejemplo:

```
posicion 0 
id= 45
cant= 2

posicion 1
id = 1488
cant= 100

posicion N
id = N
cant= X
```

o algo que de alguna manera me sirva para tener una relacion ID-CANT en una varible session.
donde pueda consultar, recorrerla, verificar si existe un id, y actualizar cantidad.
o recorrer el arreglo y eliminar uno de sus registros. o agregar um registro nuevo.

He buscado, pero no encuentro un array de arrays, solo encontre como agregar un array a una variable.
quien me pueda ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, he encontrado como recorrer crear los array de arrays en session.

Te creas una variable con un array y los campos que necesitas.

```
$productos= array(
            array('cant' => $cant, 'id' => $idproducto)
        );
```

y luego a la variable de session que te estas creando le agregas ese arreglo de productos.

```
session(['idCarrito' => $productos]);
```

Gracias, esto funcionó para mi,